# Push to a Mercurial repository (bitbucket) produces "Request Entity Too Large"?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

What does it mean when you try to push to a Mercurial repository on Bitbucket and it produces the response:

```
abort: HTTP Error 413: Request Entity Too Large
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [asking](http://bitbucket.org/help/Home) this the bitbucket team. In the meanwhile you could try using ssh access instead of http.

Comment: Switching to SSH did the trick for me. The commit I tried to push via HTTP that resulted this error was somewhat over 50 megabytes.

Comment: How do we use ssh option in bitbucket?

Comment: @AshutoshNigam: this is [how I did it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like BitBucket has a size limit on HTTP uploads and you are exceeding them. It is probably a large file that you are uploading that is breaking things. Try excluding that one file and see what happens.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E413.html

http://forums.asp.net/p/1191089/2046229.aspx#2046229

Answer (score 1):

It means that you've reached an upload limit set by Bitbucket or another thing as @TheSteve0 has pointed out.

If you are running behind nginx remember that the default upload size is 1MB. To increase it add the following to the "http" section of nginx.conf;

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 10M;
```

Then restart nginx

Comment: This solved the issue in Nginx multiple times for me, but I would uplift to higher value, for instance 1000M. Answered also here - https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pushing-to-BitBucket-Gives-quot-413-Request-Entity-Too-Large/qaq-p/650755